# What are uncaught exceptions in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

**What are uncaught exceptions (and exceptions in general) in Node.js?**

All the resources are about how to handle them, but I haven't found anything explaing what they are and why they happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An exception happens when code does something it probably shouldn't.  There are a ton of types of exceptions for all kinds of things.

For example:

```
var array = ["A", "B", "C"];
var s = array[1357].toLowerCase();
// TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

someOther.code().toRun(); // this will NOT run, execution is aborted at the exception
```

That's an exception.

*Uncaught* simply means that no code was looking for that execption so that it could be gracefully handled. Uncaught exceptions **halt execution of your code** and show up as error in the console. Uncaught exceptions are a very bad thing in production code.

You make an uncaught exception *caught* with a try/catch block. Which you probably read about in all those "how to handle them" resources you found.

```
try {
  var array = ["A", "B", "C"];
  var s = array[1357].toLowerCase();
} catch (e) {
  console.log("Don't do that, seriously");
}
someOther.code().toRun(); // this does run, execution continues after caught exception
```

Answer (score 1):

An exception is basically when something "breaks". For example:

```
alert(x);
```

will cause a "ReferenceError: x is not defined" because x has yet to be defined. This is an uncaught exception.

One way to handle exceptions is to wrap them in a simple try/catch:

```
try { 
  alert(x)
}
catch (e) {
  alert("x wasn't defined");
}
```

To keep your code running smoothly, you'll want to try and catch and handle all potential exceptions, otherwise your script will stop processing.

Read more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)